# How to group items inside custom control combobox?

Tags: wpf, combobox, grouping, collectionviewsource

I've been trying to group the items of my custom control combobox using xaml and I'm a little stuck. I've been reading around and found the following code that produces the results I want, but I'd like to move all the code into the GroupedImageComboBox control.

```
<StackPanel>

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="groupedData" Source="{Binding Items}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="EntityBaseDependencyType" Converter="{StaticResource enumConverter}"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <WPFControls:GroupedImageComboBox  
                                         ItemsSource ="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedData}}"     
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
                                      >
            <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default"/>
            </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        </WPFControls:GroupedImageComboBox>

    </StackPanel>
```

I would like to be able to remove the use of the stackpanel and the itemscontrol from this area and put them inside the GroupedImageComboBox. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1.

I've been playing with the template and feel that I should be able to do the collectionview manipulations within the DropDown grid - I'm just not sure how....

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type WPFControls:ImageComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>                        
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                                  Grid.Column="2" 
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DiplayImageWithTextDataTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"              
                             Style="{x:Null}" 
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Margin="3,3,23,3"
                             Focusable="True" 
                             Background="Transparent"
                             Visibility="Hidden"
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup Name="Popup"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide"
                           >
                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                              >
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                                />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems that in this example, the stack panel IS NOT something you HAVE TO use.

Just move the CollectionViewSource declaration elsewhere (in your `</Window.Resources><Window.Resources>` tag for example) and put your combobox anywhere else you want.

Comment: I've edited the question - and I see that this can be solved using resources outside the control but I'm sure it's possible to do it inside, I'm just not sure how!!

Comment: Well I'm a bit confused here... What is the link between what you want to do with the collection view source (i.e. data grouping as far as I understand :)) and the edit of your post... I have re-read your initial question and maybe what I'm missing here is the "but I'd like to move all the code into the GroupedImageComboBox control" part...